# .htaccess 301 redirect with an exception

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, reverse-proxy

I'm using a reverse proxy to have https://blog.example.com/ show at https://www.example.com/blog/

In order to eliminate infinite loop, I need to set up a 301 redirection from https://blog.example.com/ to https://www.example.com/blog/ with an exception of traffic coming from the main WWW domain.

This seems to work, but it fails to redirect all inner pages, like blog.example.com/folder1/, blog.example.com/folder2/, etc.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The redirect code you posted is not valid by itself - what other directives do you have? "I need to set up a 301 redirection from `https://blog.example.com/` to `https://www.example.com/blog/`" - you can't do that if the user is requesting `https://blog.example.com/` (the "reverse proxy"), but that also is not what the directive you posted is doing? "I'm using a reverse proxy to have `https://blog.example.com/` show at `https://www.example.com/blog/`" - that doesn't really make sense. You mean the user is requesting `https://blog.example.com/`, but the request is being proxied to ... (?)

Comment: I'd say your attempt is fine, you just need to invert the second condition _and_ you do not want a R=301 redirection, but an internal rewrite.

Comment: Apologies if I didn’t explain it better.
Basically, we’ve created a reverse proxy on the main website https://www.example.com/blog which points to the sub-domain https://blog.example.com/.
The challenge is that now the content is accessible at both locations. Thus the need to create a redirect for users that go to https://blog.example.com/, to be redirected to https://www.example.com/blog, while avoiding an infinite loop.

Hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" with proxying the request to a particular target URL is that according to the target server, the user is actually making a request to the target URL - that's the point of a reverse proxy.

So, if the user makes a request to `https://www.example.com/blog/` which you reverse proxy to `https://blog.example.com/` then the target server thinks you are making a request to `https://blog.example.com/` - just as if the user had made a direct request to `https://blog.example.com/`.

So, you can't simply redirect based on the URL being requested.

However, when the request passes through your proxy server then this *should* be setting various HTTP request headers - passing on information about the actual request the client is making. You could check for the absence of one of these headers - thus indicating a direct request that has not gone through your reverse proxy server.

For example, try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Host} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(blog)\.example\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/%1/$1 [R=302,L]
```

There is no need for the `<IfModule>` wrapper here.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues and only change to a 301 (permanent) when you are sure everything is working.